# Retrieving Username Using Oracle Triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am new to using triggers. What function can I use to determine who tripped my trigger?

For example:
Someone updates a row, and I want to know who updated the row.

I am using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') FROM dual;
```

or

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USERID') FROM dual;
```

Comment: This gives the oracle user. If there is some form of connection pool from a web app that does its own authentication, then that web-app may need to pass in a username (eg as CLIENT_IDENTIFIER)